# OKHttpClient Response - bad request

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp, sendgrid-api-v3

I get a response - Bad Request when making an api request using OKHttpClient. Can someone please help? Response Code - 400
https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/api_v3.html

```
 val policy = StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build()
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)

        val client = OkHttpClient()

  val body: RequestBody = RequestBody.create(
                "application/json".toMediaTypeOrNull(),
                "{\"list_ids\":[\"a7aab3b0-\"],\"contacts\":[{\"email\": \"" + userEmail + "\"}]}"
            )
            val request: Request = Request.Builder()
                .url("https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/contacts")
                .put(body)
                .addHeader("authorization", "Bearer SG.7LPq")
                .addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
                .build()
    
            val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your keys don't match the case being used in the API docs, they are capitalised. Also have you tried checking that `toMediaTypeOrNull()` is able to format that as JSON? It's difficult to tell how it will handle those slashes but they shouldn't be needed.

Comment: what do you mean by doesn't match the case used in the API docs?

Comment: The doc you linked shows parameter keys as "Content-type" and "Authorization" your code sample shows these in all lower case.

Comment: o that didn't fix it.